# Audio seek bar in JS using slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-audio

I have a slider in html,

```
 <div id="seekslider" style="width: 75%; margin: 0 auto; margin-top: 10px; display: inline-block;"></div>
```

and I want it to move as the audio plays, and also be 'seek-able.'

I know I'm doing something wrong.. Here's the mess I have so far:

```
function intializePlayer(){
audio = document.getElementById("player");
playbtn = document.getElementById("controlTogglePlay");
seekslider = document.getElementById("seekslider");
playbtn.addEventListener("click",playPause,false);
seekslider.addEventListener("change",audioSeek,false);
audio.addEventListener("timeupdate",seektimeupdate,false);
seekslider = $("#seekslider");
seekslider.slider({
    orientation: "horizantal",
    value: 25,
    range: "min",
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    step: 1,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        $("#seekslider.value").prop("seekslider", ui.value / 100);
        updateCookies();
        }
    });
}

window.onload = intializePlayer;

function audioSeek(){
    var seekto = audio.duration * (seekslider.value / 100);
    audio.currentTime = seekto;
}
function seektimeupdate(){
    var nt = audio.currentTime * (100 / audio.duration);
    seekslider.value = nt;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does your "mess" produce? How does its behavior compare to the behavior you expected?

Comment: @Jolta Bar is there, just doesnt move with the time of song or seek.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code:

```
function intializePlayer(){
    audio = document.getElementById("player");
    playbtn = document.getElementById("controlTogglePlay");
    seekslider = document.getElementById("seekslider");
    playbtn.addEventListener("click",playPause,false);
    audio.addEventListener("timeupdate",seektimeupdate, false);
    seekslider = $("#seekslider");
    seekslider.slider({
        orientation: "horizantal",
        value: 25,
        range: "min",
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        step: 1,
        slide: function(event, ui) { // CHANGED HERE
                var seekto = audio.duration * (ui.value / 100);
                console.log('seekto:', seekto); // check console to see if this is getting called.    
                audio.currentTime = seekto;
        }
    });
}

window.onload = intializePlayer;

// CHANGED HERE
function seektimeupdate(){
    var nt = audio.currentTime * (100 / audio.duration);
    console.log('nt:', nt); // check console to see if this is getting called.    
    seekslider.slider( "value", nt); // CHANGED HERE
}
```

<strike>the problem is at line 8:</strike>

```
seekslider = $("#seekslider");
```

now `seekslider` turns from htmlElement to Jquery object,

two ways to solve it,

- use a different name for the jquery object like 'jSeekslider'
- change the  `audioSeek()` and `seektimeupdate()` code to...

  ```
  function audioSeek(){
      audio.currentTime = audio.duration * (seekslider[0].value / 100);
  }
  function seektimeupdate(){
      seekslider[0].value = audio.currentTime * (100 / audio.duration);
  }
  ```

Comment: Hmm, I still dont know what I'm doing wrong. Put in the code, changed object names to jseekslider..
Still, the bar does nothing, and I'm getting 

    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0'     ofundefineddefaults.js seektimeupdate

Comment: so what library are you using to emulate the slider?

Comment: I really dont know, I honestly dont get very much of this. I look at existing code, and copy/add onto it.  

Everything that is used is right here: 

        //code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css  
        //code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js  
        code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js  
        jquery.cookie.js  
        //maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js

Comment: Edit: Thanks! It works, I missed copying the last bracket. Thanks for the help :)